# Can't validate reCAPTCHA in PHP form

Tags: php, json, recaptcha

I can't figure out why the server's response doesn't allow me to validate the recaptcha. My PHP code is:

```
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secret = "my key";   
$postdata = "secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$out = json_decode($server_output);
curl_close($ch);
if($out->success == true){/*make stuff*/} /* when the user clicks, $out->success is not true! */
```

My HTML form is quite ordinary.

```
<form method="POST" id="form">
<!-- inputs -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my key" style="margin:10px"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Valider">
</form>
```

I know the problem must be really silly. I've found a workaround which is, instead of checking if `$out->success==true`, checking if `strlen($captcha) > 1`. But I'm pretty sure it's not very likely to block robots... Any idea? Thanks...

**EDIT**: I just ran a ZAP attack on my website (ZED attack proxy, a security tool from OWASP foundation). It fails completing the sign-up form (before that, it was able to create 100 users in less than a minute!). So this means that some robots will blocked. I still want to get it done properly though...

Comment: Can you try to echo the output: `echo $out;` - what does this give you?

Comment: Hello, yes I've tried to echo it, with strval, but it's empty...

Comment: how about echoing the output before decoding it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to send your data as an array like that :

```
$postdata = array(
    'secret' => $secret,
    'response' => $captcha
);
```